# Custom Segmented Control Not Switching Views

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I made a custom UIControl:

```
import UIKit

    @IBDesignable class FeedViewSC: UIControl {

    fileprivate var labels = [UILabel]()
    var thumbView = UIView()

    var items: [String] = ["Tab1", "Tab2"] {
        didSet {
            setupLabels()
        }

    }

    var selectedIndex : Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            displayNewSelectedIndex()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var font : UIFont! = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13) {
        didSet {
            setFont()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {

        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2

        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)

        setupLabels()

        insertSubview(thumbView, at: 0)

    }


    func setupLabels() {
        for label in labels {
            label.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        labels.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

        for index in 1...items.count {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
            label.text = items[index-1]
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.font = UIFont(name: "Nunito",size: 17)
            label.textColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1)
            self.addSubview(label)
            labels.append(label)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var selectFrame = self.bounds
        let newWidth = selectFrame.width / CGFloat(items.count)
        selectFrame.size.width = newWidth
        thumbView.frame = selectFrame
        thumbView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
        thumbView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        let labelHeight = self.bounds.height
        let labelWidth = self.bounds.width / CGFloat(labels.count)

        for index in 0...labels.count - 1 {

            let label = labels[index]

            let xPosition = CGFloat(index) * labelWidth
            label.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight)
        }

    }

    override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        var calculatedIndex: Int?
        for (index, item) in labels.enumerated() {
            if item.frame.contains(location){
                calculatedIndex = index
            }
        }
        if calculatedIndex != nil {
            selectedIndex = calculatedIndex!
            sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }

        return false

    }


    func displayNewSelectedIndex (){

        if(self.selectedIndex == -1){
            self.selectedIndex = self.items.count-1
        }

        let label = labels[selectedIndex]


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.90, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

            self.thumbView.frame = label.frame

        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func setFont(){
        for item in labels {
            item.font = font
        }
    }

}
```

I emeded it into my ViewController and tried to have it programitcally switch between two views:

```
import UIKit

    class FeedViewController: UIViewController {

    let feedViewSC = FeedViewSC()

    let firstView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let secondView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let (width, height) = UIScreen.main.bounds.wh

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(firstView)
        view.addSubview(secondView)

        setupContainerViews()

        firstView.isHidden = false
        secondView.isHidden = true

        myTravel.selectedIndex = 0

        let feedControl = FeedViewSC(frame: CGRect(x: 65, y: 5, width: width-130, height: 35))
        feedControl.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(feedControl)
        feedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    func segmentedControlSwitch(_ sender: FeedViewSC) {
        switch feedViewSC.selectedIndex {

        case 0:
            firstView.isHidden = false
            secondView.isHidden = true

        case 1:
            firstView.isHidden = true
            secondView.isHidden = false


        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    func setupContainerViews() {

        firstView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        firstView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        secondView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        secondView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        secondView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        secondView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let img = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = img
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

extension CGRect {
    var wh: (w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat) {
        return (size.width, size.height)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing that's wrong. For some reason, the code does not switch between firstView and secondView. Currently, it is just showing the first view. please keep in mind i am doing this without storyboards and all programmatically.

Comment: I don't have my mac around me now. But by looking at your code, I think it might have something to do with how you call `segmentedControlSwitch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems in segmentedControlSwitch method. You should be using sender in switch case instead of local variable which might not be initialized.

```
func segmentedControlSwitch(_ sender: myTripsSC) {
    switch sender.selectedIndex {

    case 0:
        firstView.isHidden = false
        secondView.isHidden = true

    case 1:
        firstView.isHidden = true
        secondView.isHidden = false


    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Edit:
your vc should look like this:

```
import UIKit

class FeedViewController: UIViewController {

let feedViewSC = FeedViewSC()

let firstView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let secondView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let (width, height) = UIScreen.main.bounds.wh

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.addSubview(firstView)
    view.addSubview(secondView)

    setupContainerViews()

    firstView.isHidden = false
    secondView.isHidden = true

    //myTravel.selectedIndex = 0

    let feedControl = FeedViewSC(frame: CGRect(x: 65, y: 5, width: width-130, height: 35))
    feedControl.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(feedControl)
    feedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
}

func segmentedControlSwitch(_ sender: FeedViewSC) {
    switch sender.selectedIndex {

    case 0:
        firstView.isHidden = false
        secondView.isHidden = true

    case 1:
        firstView.isHidden = true
        secondView.isHidden = false


    default:
        break;
    }
}

func setupContainerViews() {

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        firstView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        firstView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        secondView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        secondView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        secondView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        secondView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let img = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = img
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}

extension CGRect {
    var wh: (w: CGFloat, h: CGFloat) {
        return (size.width, size.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I changed my action to reflect what it should be but it still isn't working

Comment: I compiled your after making the suggested change and it was working. Now issue must be somewhere else. If possible share your code.